# Can't find "Sync project with Gradle files" in Android Studio running on Mac

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I'm running into the error when I tried to run the existing project.

> Error: `"AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tag"`

I'm seeing a lot of solutions suggesting using "Sync project with Gradle files". I'm running Android Studio on my Mac and did not see that option. I do have `AndroidManifest.xml` file in the project but for some reason Android Studio can't find it.
I have the file under project_name > app > src > main > res.

I have Android Studio 4.1.1 and macOS Catalina 10.15.7

[image: Android Studio]

I also got a recommendation when I open up the Android Studio

> Migrate Project to Gradle?
> This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system.
> More Information about migrating to Gradle
> Don't show this message again.

Not sure what to do about it. I'm pretty new to Android Studio. Thanks!